# Can the same PDF document print differently than its viewed on the screen?

Tags: pdf, printing, view

For example, you send a PDF document containing an invoice to a client, you want them to view your logo in it in color on the screen but when printed, you want your logo to be printed in its printable black / white version, is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible to substitute images for printing - it may not be. Would it not an option to ask/tell the client to manually switch to s/w in the print dialog?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can have things marked for 'screen only' or 'screen + print'. At least this is what Scribus-NG let's you do IIRC

Comment: Manually switching is not what's intended. Does Scribus-NG support 'screen and/or print' in the PDF output or just in other formats? Thank you both for the comments.

Comment: This can be done using watermark annotations. You can have one watermark for the screen and another one for print. Both have to be in the same location. You can set their flags so that only one of them get displayed when printed or viewed on screen. I wrote an article for our PDFOne product based on this requirement - [Creating Alternative PDF Content For Screen and Print](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=220&t=Creating_Alternative_PDF_Content_For_Screen_and_Print).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to do it.

- Form fields can be set to "Print only" or "screen only".  "Icon Only" Pushbutton fields can have an arbitrary appearance.  Acrobat's UI will let you import any PDF page, and APIs that let you generate fields will generally let you draw your own appearances.
- Optional Content Groups (aka layers).  An OCG can have separate ON and OFF states for screen and print.  OCGs are a relatively advanced feature, only supported by more mature APIs.

I'm a fan (and contributor) to iText, a Java library which is quite capable of both methods.  It would be easier to build the icon-only button.

```
PushbuttonField iconButton = new PushbuttonField(myPdfWriter, rectangle, fieldName);
iconButton.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
iconButton.setScaleIcon(PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS);
iconButton.setVisibility(BaseField.HIDDEN_BUT_PRINTABLE);

PdfImportedPage iconAppearance = myPdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNum);
iconButton.setTemplate(iconAppearance);

myPdfWriter.addAnnotation(iconButton.getField());
```

This presumes you know the rectangle to use when generating the PDF, and have a PDF page holding the black-and-white logo.

NOTE: iText is licensed under the AGPL, which requires that anyone with access to the program's OUTPUT also have access to the source.  AKA: Commercially hostile.  Or you can buy a commercial license.  Previous versions were available under the MPL or LGPL, but are no longer supported, save in places like this, Even then the answer is increasingly "get a newer version".

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use Layers to set certain things to appear on printing and others on viewing.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PDF specification allows creation of such PDF files. But you also must use a tool that lets you take advantage of this feature in PDF specification.

Comment: @Mario Awad - Do you create a PDF file programmatically or with a tool like Acrobat?

Comment: @Sorin Nistor, I'm currently using Acrobat, but I'm looking for an answer to both as I'm working on a PHP-based system to print invoices. Thank you & have a good day :)

Comment: I do not have experience with PHP, I do not know the available PHP libraries that support layers (aka optional content). With Acrobat you cannot create simple layers, you can only create one background, one watermark and one header/footer. For demo purposes I created this file: http://www.o2sol.com/download/layers.pdf . It uses a background layer for printing and a watermark layer for display. Technically there are no differences between watermark and background layers.

Comment: I see. Now I know "layers" exist and I can search for that functionality when needed. Thank you. (However, I couldn't get your demo file to print differently than it displays!). Thanks again.

Comment: I used Adobe Reader for printing the file, I'm not sure if other readers handle the layer functionality correctly. There is an answer from VSU that recommends to use annotations. This is another approach that can be used and I'm sure that annotation functionality is easier to be found in PDF libraries than layer functionality. However there is a problem with this approach, Adobe Reader has an option to print only page content and no annotations and in this situation your logo will not be printed at all.